# Codeigniter hook is not executed

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I created a hook for log all http requests in codeigniter 3 but no log is recorded after send a http request like POST or GET.

I enabled hook config in **config/config.php** :

```
$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
```

and added hook in **config/hooks.php** :

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = array(
    'class' => 'Http_request_logger',
    'function' => 'log_all',
    'filename' => 'http_request_logger.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks',
    'params' => array()
);
```

And i created a hook file in **application/hooks/http_request_logger.php** :

```
<?php 

if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Http_request_logger {

    public function log_all() {
        log_message('info', 'new request' . 'created from hook.');
        $CI = & get_instance();
        log_message('info', 'GET --> ' . var_export($CI->input->get(null), true));
        log_message('info', 'POST --> ' . var_export($CI->input->post(null), true));                
        log_message('info', '$_SERVER -->' . var_export($_SERVER, true));
    }

}

?>
```

But nothing in the log file **application/logs** folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research, I realized that I have to make some changes in the config to write the log . **config/config.php** :

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 4;


$config['log_path'] = FCPATH . '/application/logs/';
```

after change log_threshold and log_path my code works fine.